# Can I control the lights in my Subnautica base?

Tags: subnautica

I'm a big fan of *A E S T H E T I C* in the survival crafting games that I play, and I like spending time making things look nice. One of the bigger annoyances for me is how BRIGHT my base is, with every room being lit up like the sun at all times.

Aside from my base losing its power source, which comes with other rough tradeoffs like a lack of oxygen, is there any way to control the light sources in my base?

Answer (score 6):

Not in the vanilla game (other than losing power.) But you can install the [light switch mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/subnautica/mods/460) and use e.g. the lamp from the [decorations mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/subnautica/mods/46) to provide "mood lighting", or "outdoor" lights shining through windows - or bioluminescent flora in the ACU.

And of course you can customize Cyclops into a base. It has an interior light switch.

Comment: Well SF, I appreciate your answer, but not the answer I was looking for, as I'm on PS4. @Wrigglenite decided to step in with my OP because "it doesn't matter", but the answer for me is just "no". Thanks.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Or unleash your Feng Shui and make Cyclops beautiful. Plus one more point: with late-game oxygen tanks you can spend ages in an unpowered base before you need to power it up for a couple seconds to replenish air. You can even sleep in bed without air.